# Последний символ строки игнорирует условие его проверки

Tags: c++

Необходимо ограничить ввод в строку таким образом, чтобы в строке были только символы 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A' и длина строки была кратна трем.
При проверке введеных символов появилась проблема. При вводе 'CATCGTAATGACGGCCTТ' и подобных  наборов символов, условие:

```
     if (d[i] == d0[j])
        {
            e++;
            break;
        }
```

по какой-то причине, обходит стороной последний символ 'T', т.е не выполняет условие, когда 'T' = 'T', хотя программа его видит и считывает в соответствующую переменную.

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
int x = 0, size = 0, e, k3 = 0, k, u = 0;
string d, d1, d0 = "GCTA";
do
{
    cout << "Введите d: " << endl;
    cin >> d;
    e = 0;
    k3 = d.size() % 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d0.size(); j++)
        {
            if (d[i] == d0[j])
            {
                e++;
                break;
            }

        }
       
    }
    
    if (e != d.size() || (k3 != 0))
    {
        cout << "Повторите ввод" << endl;
    }
    
} while (e != d.size() || (k3 != 0));
```

Прошу помочь решить и объяснить данную проблему.

Comment: А зачем вообще считать правильные символы в строке? Если Вас попросить сварить все пельмени, то Вы сначала пересчитаете их, потом, бросая их в кипяток, пересчитаете их ещё раз, а при несовпадении результатов выбросите кастрюлю? Устанавливайте флаг пред внутренним циклом, при совпадении с любой буквой сбрасывайте его, если сразу после внутреннего цикла флаг всё ещё установлен, то буква не правильная, брейк во внешнем цикле, после любого завершения внешнего проверяйте флаг, если он утсановлен или остаток не равен нолю, то cout << "Повторите ввод" << endl;.

Comment: Проверка длины и лишних букв – это понятно. А что делать, если введённый ген не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вашего вопроса не понятно что является  ограничением. Это неудачное завершение или  обработка исключительной ситуации или установка флага или еще что то?.. Но то, что вы пытаетесь делать,   можно сделать много проще и разными способами, но не таким многословным способом, как у вас. Пример кода:

```
const char d[] = "GCTA";
std::string s;
/*пока ввод строки корретен
и длина строки не кратна трем
и в строке есть какой нибудь другой символ кроме заданных
выводится сообщение об ошибке*/
while (cin >> s && (s.size() % 3 ||
    s.find_first_not_of(d) != s.npos))
{
    std::cerr << "error...try again\n";
}
```

по моему отражает то, что вы хотели делать.

Comment: Выглядит элегантно.

Comment: Софтина должна принимать только текстовое представление генетических последовательностей, это же очевидно.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибки в коде нет, у вас ошибка во входной строчке - последняя T не латинская, а из кириллицы. Замените её на букву T из латиницы и у вас всё заработает.